# How to improve loading performance of @font-face

Tags: performance, compression, font-face

I use a chinese custom font-face called YaHei. For the implementation I used http://fontface.codeandmore.com/, but the font face file is 10.01MB. Is there a way to compress the file or to improve the loading performance, before  the font is cached by browser?
I tried to use prefetching with `<link rel="prefetch" href="#" />`, but I didn't notice any difference.

Answer (score 0):

There are some useful tips here: http://www.artzstudio.com/2012/02/web-font-performance-weighing-fontface-options-and-alternatives/

Look especially at the section 'Removing Excess Font Glyphs'